# How to resolve() Promise after Observable success

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2, angular-promise, angular2-observables

I have this scenario.

```
// this is in myService.ts
public myFunction() {
 return new Promise((resolve) => {
  let click = Observable.fromEvent(window, "click");

  this.myStream = click
    .map(() => Observable.timer(10000))
    .switch()
    .subscribe(() => {
      // show alert here
    });

 });
}

// this is in home.ts page

ngOnInit() {

 this.myService.myFunction().then(() => {
 //simulate click at start
    let event = new MouseEvent("click", {bubbles: true});
    this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(
      this.simulateClick.nativeElement, "dispatchEvent", [event]);
 });
}
```

My question is where to write **resolve()**. What I need is, **Observable.fromEvent** to success and after that to do the click simulation. If I write resolve()  let's say under the line **let click = Observable.fromEvent(window, "click");** then simulate click is first then Observable.fromEvent.

Answer (score 2):

for angular2 observables, the simple and clean way is turn `Observable` into `Promise` and return.

download [toPromise extension](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/topromise.md) if it's not there.

```js
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

public myFunction() {
    return Observable.fromEvent(window, "click")
        .map(() => Observable.timer(10000))
        .switch()
        .toPromise();
}
```

Comment: This is not solving the solution. I need to subscribe to this event.

Comment: Why? It already does one time subscribe for you. You can then `myFunction().then` should does what you need.